# expressionengine Remove question mark from url after search submit

Tags: .htaccess, expressionengine

I have a multi-language website and my second language goes to a subdirectory `mysite.com/en/`. Everything is fine but the search functionality. When I submit my search, it prints a question mark right after the subdirectory like this:

```
mysite.com/en/?/noresult/6bc629a9319d90a1e9703eaf2c00f7cd/
```

And because of it my site redirects to the homepage. I searched and tried many `.htaccess` codes but it did not work. The URL without question mark works fine.

Here is my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /en/

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)/index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Please can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep directory slash off and then add a trailing slash using rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectorySlash Off  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /en/

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)/index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # add a trailing slash to directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/en/$1 -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ /en%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,NE,R=302]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i checked, same problem

Comment: Unfortunately commenting with **same problem** won't help. Are you doing a FORM post? Open Chrome dev tool and then do search and see if there is a 301 redirect or your form action is causing this.

Comment: yes it's doing a form post to "mysite.com/en/" and GET url is "mysite.com/en/?/noresult/6bc629a9319d90a1e9703eaf2c00f7cd/"